# How to resolve shared Package and Project references in .net6?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-6.0

I have a .net471 project that I'm currently trying to upgrade to .net6, that we'll call Project A.

Project A has a `ProjectReference` to Project B.
Project A also has numerous `PackageReferences`.
One of these `PackageReferences`, Package C, has a `PackageReference` to Package B, which is a nuget package of Project B.

So, A references B and C, and C also references a *version* of B.

Under .net471, everything works just fine. Some voodoo magic is happening which seems to allow all of the references to resolve, and the only dll from Project B present, is the Project B build dll. (The nuget version doesn't appear to be present).

Under .net6, everything builds, looks the same as before, the Project B dll is present (NOT the nuget Package B), but when the code runs, Package C now tries to call Package B, but fails, since the versioned dll is not present.

Currently, the only thing I can come up with that may have been allowing .net471 to work is a `AutoGenerateBindingRedirects` tag in the csproj. However, that tag doesn't seem to yield any changes in my .net6 project.

Pulling out the project reference in favor of a nuget reference isn't at the top of our list of solutions. What options are available that would allow the project reference to remain, and will satisfy the packages need for a versioned dll?

Answer (score -1):

According to this [article](https://www.erikheemskerk.nl/transitive-nuget-dependencies-net-core-got-your-back/) adding something like this in `csproj` should unify different versions of the same assembly at runtime.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Here is the link to [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection) if you want to research more about how **Assembly Unification** works.

Comment: I've tried messing around with this a bit, but it doesn't seem to be resulting in any changes. Some of the tags don't even come up in autocomplete. 

The article describes a situation almost similar to mine, but not quite what I'm encountering.